# Java Regex Matcher mistake

Tags: java, regex

My string:
2017.11.22 SAMPLE NEWS - I am some text here and there
2018.12.30 SAMPLE NEWS2 - I am some text here and there

countLine():

```
public static int countLines(String filename) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
        try {
            byte[] c = new byte[1024];
            int count = 0;
            int readChars = 0;
            boolean endsWithoutNewLine = false;
            while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i) {
                    if (c[i] == '\n')
                        ++count;
                }
                endsWithoutNewLine = (c[readChars - 1] != '\n');
            }
            if (endsWithoutNewLine) {
                ++count;
            }
            return count;
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    }
```

My code to match regex on the string - loadTextFromFile():

```
public static String loadTextFromFile(String filename, int type) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String match = "";
        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        if (type == 0) { // Match date
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4}[\\.]\\d{2}[\\.]\\d{2})").matcher(line);
                while (m.find()) {
                    match = m.group(1).trim();
                    System.out.println("date: " + match);
                }
            }
        } else { 
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                Matcher m = Pattern.compile("((?!.*[\\d+\\.?\\d+]).*$)").matcher(line);
                while (m.find()) {
                    match = m.group(1).trim();
                    System.out.println("text: " + match);
                }
            }
        }
        return match;
    }
```

main():

```
String date, string;
        for (int i = 0; i < countLines(FILE_NAME); i++) {
            date = loadTextFromFile(FILE_NAME, 0);
            string = loadTextFromFile(FILE_NAME, 1);
            System.out.println("date:" + i + " " + date);
            System.out.println("string:" + i + " " + string);
        }
```

Output:

```
date:0 2018.12.30  
string:0   
date:1 2018.12.30   
string:1   
count: 2
```

I am sure this is an issue with regex but i can't understand where it is. I debugged the application and checked, it goes into while(m.find()) twice, making the `string=""`, means that it finds more than one matches for the regex.

but how do i solve this, I just want to extract the `SAMPLE NEWS - I am some text here and there` with the regex.

Comment: I believe you can simple do this:  String s =str.replaceFirst("(\\d{4}[\\.]\\d{2}[\\.]\\d{2})",""); You do not need the Matchers etc.

Comment: (?=SAMPLE NEWS -).*$, does this regex will match your expect?

Comment: What do you want to search? [.] is a dot, while [\\.] is \ or . Secondly, use FileReader and BufferedReader for reading a text file. BufferedReader br = ...; String nextLine = br.readLine();

Comment: @akshayapandey Don't want to replace/change anything, just want to extract and display.

Comment: @YanKhonski -  I just want to extract the SAMPLE NEWS - Travel settlement is now even easier ֠check out the new features

Comment: @AforApple ..sure so just assign it to a different variable. You will have your desired string in the new variable. The original string remain unaffected

Comment: @yudongshen Yes it works.

Comment: @akshayapandey Thanks man, This method is way more simple.